# lim (1+x)^n when x is in the set [0,1]

Tags: limits

I was wondering what is the lim(1+x)^n  when x is in the interval [0,1]when n goes to infinity does it exist?

Thank You

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$(1+x)^n=\begin{cases}1\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}1&,\;\;\;x=0\\{}\\(1+x)^n\stackrel{\text{Bernoulli}}\ge1+nx\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\infty&,\;\;\;x>0\end{cases}$$

Comment: Sorry I meant interval [0,1]

Comment: @user142775 Yes. That's what I understood and based on that I wrote my answer. Ok, I see what you mean: that was a typo: it should be $\;x>0\;$ .

Comment: Cheers, you are right